# take count of values from a dataframe which are separated by a comma

Tags: python

I've a dataframe 'genres', where value of each row in column is separated by  ','. I need to take count of each value, such that comedy 2, drama 7 and so on. Tried many methods nut failed.

I  tried `genres = trending.groupby(['genre']).size()` but this line considers values `'Comedy,Crime,CriticallyAcclaimed'` as one . I'm new to python, please help me.

```
genre
Comedy,Crime,CriticallyAcclaimed
Comedy,Drama,Romance
Drama
Drama
Drama,Hollywood
Drama,Romance
Drama,Romance
Drama,Romance,Classic
```

Comment: only the first entry in the genre list need to be counted in each unique case? that is Drama should be 6 or 7 ?

Comment: no ,not the first entry. drama should be 7..

Comment: Then update your question! Now it says drama 6.

Comment: Do you know beforehand the maximum number of items in one row? Is there a limit? At the moment, in your example, it seems that there won't be more than three items in each row. Is that true?

Comment: @Dataman there is no limit. It can be any number

Comment: You can read all the lines of your input, splitting each of them by `comma` and keeping a dict of each value found, incrementing the counters.

Comment: What does `type(trending.groupby(['genre']))` output? And `print(trending.groupby(['genre']))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer:

```
genres = pd.DataFrame(genres.genre.str.split(',', expand=True).stack(), columns= ['genre'])  
genres = genres.reset_index(drop = True)  
genre_count = pd.DataFrame(genres.groupby(by = ['genre']).size(),columns = ['count'])  
genre_count = genre_count.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pandas`, what even not said in the OP can be guessed, you could do something similar to this:

```
from collections import Counter

// Code where you get trending variable

genreCount = Counter()
for row in trending.itertuples():
    genreCount.update(row[0].split(",")) // Change the 0 for the position where the genre column is

print(genreCount) // It works as a dict where keys are the genres and values the appearances
print(dict(genreCount)) // You can also turn it inot a dict but the Counter variable already works as one
```

Comment: Your example spit out:
    `genreCount.update(row['genre'].split(","))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`

    change to:
    `for row in trending['genre']:
        genreCount.update(row.split(","))`

Comment: True, its a `tuple` not a `namedtuple`, I have to idnex by number not key.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is assuming that you know already the maximum number of the items in one row. This means that you need to read the file once and find this information (here we are assuming this number is 3 based on your example).

```
max_num_of_items_in_one_row = 3
cols = range(max_num_of_items_in_one_row)
df = pd.read_csv('genre.txt', names=cols, engine='python', skiprows=1)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 'NA' if x==None else x)
all_ = df.values.flatten()
genres = np.unique(all_)
for y in genres:
    tmp = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x==y else 0)
    print(y, tmp.values.flatten().sum())
```

The code, reads the file into a dataframe, gets rid of None values, find all the unique values in the dataframe and count the number of their occurrences in the dataframe.